# How to execute net use command in nant script?

Tags: batch-file, nant

I have  a network shared folder, I want to copy some files there, using nant script, I have tried below given code, but it's not working.

```
  <exec program="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" failonerror="false" >
     <arg line="net use I=\\192.168.1.1\TestFolder" />
   </exec>
```

any help?

Comment: I don't have any experience with `nant` but it is worth mentioning that the syntax of the `net use` command is: `net use [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]` Replace the equal sign between the device name and the UNC path with a colon (`I:`) and add a space between the two parameters.

Comment: I tend to avoid mapping drives. Just define a property with the UNC location (`\\computer\share`), and use that property instead of the drive letter.